# Tabletop Live Edge Sculpting issue

Tags: modeling, sculpting, photorealism

I've tried to create something like this:
[image]

I made frame and simple box on top of the frame but had a problem of creating natural wooden edges with sculpting but run into this:

[image]

Can somebody show how to do that with sculpting or deform modifier (as I remember there was quite useful box deform modifier in 3ds Max)?

PS I tried, Triangulate, Subdivide Surface and Dynamic Topology. Just cant understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: There is too different amount of edge loops for the thickness of the table compared to its width. Sculpt likes everything to be even. So if working with quads (preferred for sculpting with Multires) try to make them all relatively even (of the same size). Also make sure to press Ctrl+A > Scale in Object mode to apply scale to object data

Comment: why don't you make a cube, and in Edit mode scale it, add some subdivisions, move the edges so that it's a bit uneven, add a Subdivision Surface modifier, then some edge loops to sharp some angles. Then you'll create a wood material with a Bump node to fake some more reliefs.

Comment: @MrZak, thanks! I just forgot to apply scale. Can you please post same answer I will mark it as correct?